# Alternate proof of convergence without using neighborhoods

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, alternative-proof

Let $c$ be some fixed real number. Let ($a_n$)$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence such that for every natural number $n$, $a_n\in\left(c-\frac1 n, c + \frac{1}n\right)$. Prove or disprove: ($a_n$)$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $c$.

I have seen similar proofs using neighborhoods. Is there a way to prove this without using that this set is a neighborhood of $c$? Is there a way to prove this using just the delta-epsilon definition of continuity?

Comment: Sure: if $x \in \left(c-\frac{1}{n},c+\frac{1}{n}\right)$, then $|x-c| < \frac{1}{n}$ (and vice versa).

Comment: I thought that was the way to approach the problem, but I wasn't sure if it was sufficient enough to say without using the "neighborhood" aspect

Comment: Given $\epsilon>0$, you need to pick $N>0$ such that $\frac{1}N<\epsilon$. Then if $n>N$ then $|a_n-c|<\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$.